# JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back, nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException

Tags: java, spring, exception, transactions, rollback

I am getting `UnexpectedRollbackException`. Here is the complete stack trace:

```
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1031)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:732)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:701)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:321)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:635)
    at com.cmates.userIcon.service.IconUpdaterServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$78838aa7.persist(<generated>)
    at com.cmates.userIcon.service.ScheduledIconUpdaterServiceImpl.doScheduledTask(ScheduledIconUpdaterServiceImpl.java:125)
    at com.cmates.profile.services.IconSyncSingletonImpl.process(IconSyncSingletonImpl.java:121)
    at com.cmates.profile.services.IconSyncJob.executeInternal(IconSyncJob.java:25)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:86)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException
    at org.objectweb.jotm.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:245)
    at org.objectweb.jotm.Current.commit(Current.java:488)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1028)
    ... 13 more
[18 Apr 2011 00:54:00,590] ERROR ErrorLogger - Job (DEFAULT.iconSyncJob threw an exception.
```

This Exception suddenly started showing in my logs. I didn't made any changes in my code.
I guess this might be due to a timeout?

Comment: could it be that as with time, there is more and more data that this transaction sifts through and the queries etc. are taking longer than earlier. Especially since there is no change in the code. This could be  plausible

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a mention of a quartz job in the stacktrace. Looks like something has setup a periodic job and the AOP transaction management has picked up on it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your transaction lasts than transaction timeout limit. You should increase transaction timeout limit..

But I am not sure about that, you should post more stack trace to understand the reason of rollback.